# How to delete using DataSet and DataAdapter C#/asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image]How can I delete a row from Database using DataSet and DataAdapter (I'm not allowed to SqlCommand)>

Table has four columns

**UserId(auto-generated) |   UserName    |    Age    |       Salary**

I tried the code below but it throws NUll Exception when i click Button3_Click(Delete Button)

**System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
System.Data.DataRowCollection.Find(...) returned null.**

```
    string s = 
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["student"].ConnectionString;
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(s))
         {
            string query = "select * from student";
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query,con))
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                ds.Tables[0].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { 
                ds.Tables[0].Columns["UserName"] };
                ViewState["query"] = query;
                ViewState["dataset"] = ds;
            }
        }
    }




 protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(s))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new 

             SqlDataAdapter((string)ViewState["query"],con))
            {

                DataSet ds = (DataSet)ViewState["dataset"];

                ds.Tables[0].Rows.Find("'" + TextBox2.Text + "'").Delete();
                SqlCommandBuilder com = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
                da.Update(ds);


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `DataRowCollection.Find` returns `null` when the key passed wasn't found, so in this case `TextBox2.Text` is not contained in the DataTable. Note that storing a whole DataSet in the ViewState is a bad idea. You send a huge string to the client even if he doesn't need it

Comment: it takes a string from textbox as the UserName(which is primary key)

Comment: Yes and that is not in the table. With LINQ following returns 0: `ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Count(r => r.Field<string>("UserName")==TextBox2.Text)`

Comment: I inserted a picture and you can see there is aaron which exist in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that `UserId` is the primary-key of your DataTable. So you can use [`DataRowCollection.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowcollection.find?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataRowCollection_Find_System_Object_)(if no key is defined you get a `MissingPrimaryKeyException`). But of course you need to specify the `UserId` and not the `UserName`. Otherwise `Find` returns `null` which causes your exception. Your screenshot shows that you are passing the `UserName`

Instead of `Find` you can use LINQ:

```
DataRow rowToDelete =  ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
   .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Field<string>("UserName") == TextBox2.Text.Trim());
if(rowToDelete != null) 
{
    rowToDelete.Delete();
    // ...
}
```